# Como obter o mês ou dia da semana em português no C#?

Tags: c#

No PHP, através da função `strftime`, consigo retornar o nome do dia da semana ou do mês, no idioma instalado no sistema operacional.

Exemplo:

```
echo strftime("%d %B", time());
```

Resultado:

> 16 Janeiro

Preciso escrever a data por extenso em C# em português e gostaria de saber se tem como fazer igual no PHP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(now.ToString(@"d  MMMM", new CultureInfo("PT-pt")));
```

Resultado

> 16  janeiro

[Exemplo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PGk3z2)

Primeiro você pega a data atual

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
```

Então converte ela para string usando o método `ToString` e a formata utilizando o primeiro paramento `@"d  MMMM"` e no segundo parâmetro você define o idioma utilizando o objeto `CultureInfo`.

Comment: Isso ai não irá se basear no idioma do sistema apenas? Fiz um teste no ideone aqui e me retornou em inglês.

Comment: Vou editar a resposta, realmente não reparei neste detalhe

Comment: Editada mostrando em português, obrigado @ArticunoL :)

Comment: Agora ta exibindo em português no ideone :)

Answer (score 1):

Podes fazer assim, que tens liberdade de controlar o formato da data e o idioma.

```
        CultureInfo pt = new CultureInfo("pt-PT",false);
        string dateFormatString = pt.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern;

        string data =  DateTime.Now.ToString(dateFormatString,new CultureInfo("pt-PT"));
```

Neste caso

> 16 de janeiro de 2019

Comment: Mas esse codigo ai nao irá exibir em inglês? A pergunta diz que deseja exibir em português.

Comment: Testei seu codigo no ideone e ele apresenta a data por extenso em inglês.

Comment: Sim, se quisers em PT é so mudar para pt-PT

Comment: Seria interessante você editar a resposta com isso então, já que é uma exigencia da pergunta ser **em portugues**.

Comment: Já está. Foi propositado para se ver como funciona.

Comment: Sergio, fiz um teste novamente no ideone, e a data por extenso continua exibindo em inglês no ideone. Acredito que está dependente do sistema em que está em execução, isso pode ser um problema pro autor.

Comment: O meu sistema está rodando em todo em EN.

Comment: Veja por si mesmo: https://ideone.com/qXj3GV

Comment: @ArticunoL Tem razão, fiz o teste no https://dotnetfiddle.net/ e está em EN. É sesnsivel ao idiona do utilizador, no meu caso apesar do sistema estar em EN o meu idioma está em PT

Comment: @ArticunoL assim está no idioma esperado. Obrigado.